# Displaying Multiple Videos In Flutter

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, flutter-layout, android-videoview

I'm trying to display a list of videos on my UI just like the way the Youtube app is. But my issue is i just cant find how to display the list of videos using the VideoPlayer plugin. The video player plugin takes just a `VideoPlayerController` and i don't know how to set all the list of videos to the controller so when they user tap on any video it plays. Or would i have to create lots of `VideoPlayerController` in a loop and assign them to each video in the list?

Answer (score 1):

**Add Dependency**

```
chewie: ^0.9.10
```

Overall, for showing youtube like list, you need separate thumbnail images, so that on clicked specific video can be played.

Run below code, where everything is available which you required.

https://github.com/codemissions/flutter-video-streaming-app

Answer (score 1):

just create new variable call path

`String? _path`;

then

```
_controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(_path!);
```

now, you can passing the path variable from resource that you have